# Replacing some special characters between quotes

Tags: java, regex, quotes, replaceall

I want to replace dot and single apostrophe characters within a JSON string, ie only when quoted. Using this input:

```
String json = "{\"someJsonMap\":{\"with.dot.s\":1.0,\"'with.dots'.and.apostroph's.\":20.001}}";
```

I want to turn this:

```
{"someJsonMap":{"with.dot.s":1.0,"with.dots'.and.apostroph's":20.001}}
```

into this:

```
{"someJsonMap":{"withdots":1.0,"withdotsandapostrophs":20.001}}
```

I appreciate any help, solutions or explanations.

Comment: Not my downvote, but you should be using a JSON parser here most likely.  Even if you hack it with a regex, if the structure changes later on, your code could easily break.

Comment: This is somewhat tricky to do correctly with regular expressions. Consider for example `{"with.dot.and\"quote": 1}`.

Comment: @Henry that's a quote char, not an apostrophe char

Comment: Thanks for your comments, I guess I'll use a parser for safety reasons as proposed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there are never escaped quotes, then you use a look ahead for an *odd* number of quotes that follow. An odd number means you are inside quotes.

```
json = json.replaceAll("['.](?=(([^\"]*\"){2})*[^\"]*\"[^\"]*$)", "");
```

That trainwreck of a regex asserts that there's an odd number of quotes following by consuming multiples (0-n via `*`) of pairs of quotes `([^\"]*\"){2}` with the remaining chars having only one quote `[^\"]*\"[^\"]*$`

If there *are* escaped quotes, you basically can't use regex.

Comment: Thanks! I accepted your answer because of your explanations and it works as expected. Even if there shouldn't be any escaped quotes in my use case, I cant be sure about that and therefore will use a JSON parser.